# Sequelize association json response problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize on my NodeJS application.

When i use **'include'** at my json response, then foreign key part is coming as json object.

I need to see this as string.

How can i do that? thank you.

[image]

Id like to do

```
kitapIsim : "hey sey"
```

Now : `"kitapIsim": {
                "kitap_adi": "her sey",
                "kitap_resmi": "FOTO"
            }`

Comment: please show code

Comment: I added @Rafael